# Show that all the integer solution of $a^n = b^m$ are given by $a = t^{m/gcd(n,m)}$ , $b = t ^ {n/gcd(n,m)}$ , for some integer $t$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

The quiz of the course of number theory is coming. But I don't really know where to start to deal with this excercise. Can anyone help me?

Question:

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers. Show that all the integer solution of $a^n = b^m$ are given by $a = t^{m/gcd(n,m)}$ , $b = t ^ {n/gcd(n,m)}$ , for some integer $t$.

Comment: Start with $a$ being prime, then maybe try induction on the number of distinct prime factors of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use prime factorization of $a$ and $b$ and compare the power of each prime on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $a$ and $b$ are composite numbers, unless they are equal. Let $a = \prod_{i = 1} ^ {k} p_i ^ {m_i}$ and $b = \prod_{i = 1} ^ {\ell} q_i ^ {n_i}$. Essentially, we have $k = \ell$ and $p_i = q_i$ for any $i \leqslant k$. We then have $\prod_{i = 1} ^ {k} p_i ^ {m_i n} = \prod_{i = 1} ^ {k} p_i ^ {n_i m}$, and thus we have $m_i \cdot n = n_i \cdot m$, whence your claim follows.